# Populate table content from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a simple table like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="2017-04-10"></td>
            <td id="2017-04-11"></td>
            <td id="2017-04-12"></td>
            <td id="2017-04-13"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How from this json file, I can insert the value `text` corresponding to the date I have in my table ?

```
"datas": {
    "2017-04-10": {
        "text": "My blue text",
        "color": "blue"
    },
    "2017-04-11": {
        "text": "My red text",
        "color": "red"
    },
    "2017-04-12": {
        "text": "My orange text",
        "color": "orange"
    },
    "2017-04-13": {
        "text": "My green text",
        "color": "green"
    }
}
```

So the desired output should be:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="2017-04-10">My blue text</td>
            <td id="2017-04-11">My red text</td>
            <td id="2017-04-12">My orange text</td>
            <td id="2017-04-13">My green text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is it possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using **`jQuery`** **:**

```js
var jsonObj = {
  "datas": {
    "2017-04-10": {
      "text": "My blue text",
      "color": "blue"
    },
    "2017-04-11": {
      "text": "My red text",
      "color": "red"
    },
    "2017-04-12": {
      "text": "My orange text",
      "color": "orange"
    },
    "2017-04-13": {
      "text": "My green text",
      "color": "green"
    }
  }
};

for (var i in jsonObj.datas) {
  $("#"+i).append(jsonObj.datas[i].text);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
      <td id="2017-04-10"></td>
      <td id="2017-04-11"></td>
      <td id="2017-04-12"></td>
      <td id="2017-04-13"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the data and change the `textContent` properties accordingly:

```js
var data = {
  "datas": {
    "2017-04-10": {
      "text": "My blue text",
      "color": "blue"
    },
    "2017-04-11": {
      "text": "My red text",
      "color": "red"
    },
    "2017-04-12": {
      "text": "My orange text",
      "color": "orange"
    },
    "2017-04-13": {
      "text": "My green text",
      "color": "green"
    }
  }
};

Object.keys(data.datas).map(function (date) {
  document.getElementById(date).textContent = data.datas[date].text;
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="2017-04-10"></td>
      <td id="2017-04-11"></td>
      <td id="2017-04-12"></td>
      <td id="2017-04-13"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You didn't mention it, but I bet you want to use those colors to change the text color (or do something similar), in which case you can modify the `style.color` property inside your loop:

```js
var data = {
  "datas": {
    "2017-04-10": {
      "text": "My blue text",
      "color": "blue"
    },
    "2017-04-11": {
      "text": "My red text",
      "color": "red"
    },
    "2017-04-12": {
      "text": "My orange text",
      "color": "orange"
    },
    "2017-04-13": {
      "text": "My green text",
      "color": "green"
    }
  }
};

Object.keys(data.datas).map(function (date) {
  var dateCell = document.getElementById(date);
  dateCell.textContent = data.datas[date].text;
  dateCell.style.color = data.datas[date].color;
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="2017-04-10"></td>
      <td id="2017-04-11"></td>
      <td id="2017-04-12"></td>
      <td id="2017-04-13"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```